# LogParser and multiple query string arguments with the same name

Tags: iis, logparser

I'm trying to get IIS logs statistics with LogParser, and I have to group numbers by the values that a certain argument, named 't', can assume on the query string. We have to handle scenarios like this one:

```
.../?t=act&t=fcst&t=be
```

where the same argument is specified more that once, and when I do the count I would like to have such an url to count 1 for each value that t assumes on the query string. Using:

```
EXTRACT_VALUE(cs-uri-query,'t')
```

only the first occurrence of t (=act) is processed, so my counts does not get increased for values fcst and be.

Is there a way to handle such a case without further post-processing?

Answer (score 2):

How about `SELECT SUM(STRCNT(cs-uri-query, 't='))` ?